# Get Checkbox IDs Serverside C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, server-side

I have created an asp.net (C#) web page that dynamically creates a table. one of the columns in the table is a checkbox that has an ID(int). I want to use the IDs of all the checked boxes in a SQL Query like so:

```
select *
from table
where ID in (1,2,3,4)
```

Is there a way that I can get a list of the IDs from all of the checked boxes serverside?

here is a snippet of the code im using to generate the checkbox:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   string Compatible_Controls = (
       "<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='CheckBox' ID='" +(dr["id"]) + "' /></td>" +
        "<td>" + (dr["Control_Name"]) + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + (dr["Control_Statement"]) + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + (dr["Regulation_type"]) + "</td>" +
       "</tr>" );
```

here is what is generated:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type='CheckBox' ID='3' /></td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxx</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking for. Do you want to read which checkboxes where checked by the user after a postback? Or do you want to read it on the server-side after you created it?

Answer (score 1):

No, the `id` attribute doesn't get posted to the server.  You can, however, use the `name` attribute to distinguish between `input` elements.  Something like this:

```
<input type='CheckBox' name='3' />
```

Or, if you still want to have the `id` attribute for use in your CSS/JavaScript, you can have both:

```
<input type='CheckBox' name='3' ID='3' />
```

Then in the server-side code the form collection would contain keys for all of the different `name` values posted there.  (Make sure the `name`s are unique on your client-side form, of course.)  You don't mention whether you're using WebForms or MVC, so there are various ways in which you can access this information when it's posted to the server.  If WebForms, [`Request.Form` will contain the key/value pairs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx).  If MVC, just add [a `FormCollection` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection) to the controller action and it will have the key/value pairs.